# calculation on keypress/keydown/keyup event in html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, asp.net, event-handling

i have 25 rows on a form for user entering the item code in (input tag) and qty (input tag) against that item code in java script calculate the value of that item's quantity and show them in amount (input tag)
The **Event fired in the onKeypress/up/down** is following

```
function qtycal() {

    for (i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {

        var quantity_j = document.getElementById("quantity_" + i);
        var price_j = document.getElementById("price_" + i);
        var amount_j = document.getElementById("amount_" + i);

        amount_j.value = price_j.value * quantity_j.value;


    } // end of for
```

as in this fired on keypress/down/up

the problem is
when i typed first digit it not calculate the value and show in amount and after entering second digit event again fired but not multyply whole value of quantity_j with price_j

How to make event so it give exact amount.

The html code

```
    <table border="1"  align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>Item Name</th>
<th>Item Code</th>
<!--<th>Stock</th>-->
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Price</th>
<!--<th>Discount %</th>
<th>Amount</th>-->
<!--<th>Discount Amount</th>-->
<th>Net Amount</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<?php for($i=1 ; $i<=25 ; $i++) { ?>

<tr>
<th> <?php echo "$i"; ?> </th>
<td><input id="itemName_<?php echo $i; ?>"  onBlur="test()" class="orderInput" type="text" align="center"  ></td>
<td><input id="itemCode_<?php echo $i; ?>"   onBlur="loaditem()"  class="orderInput" type="text" align="center" ></td>
<td><input id="quantity_<?php echo $i; ?>"    onBlur="qtycal()" class="orderInput"  type="text" align="center" ></td>
<td><input id="price_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="orderInput" type="text" align="center"  readonly></td>
<td><input id="amount_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="orderInput" type="text" align="center" readonly ></td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
</tbody>

<tfoot>
<tr>
<td id="tdTotal" colspan="2" style="font-size:16px"> <b>Totals</b></td>
<td id="totalspace" colspan="3"> </td>
<td><input id="netTotalAll" class="orderInput" type="text" readonly> </td>
</tr>

<button id="addBtn"  ><img src="images/add.png" align="middle"></button>

</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: i think OP have keyup not keydown

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 Why is your username > int64

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 html code pasted see it.

Comment: @Atif Mohammed Ameenuddin - idk.. ask chuck norris

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you have to bind your function to the keyup to get the actual value.

If that doesn't work you can put a little delay to your function using setTimeout("qtycal", 100). It will not be noted by your users and will make your calculation works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calculating it just fine, but amount_j is not a reference to the DOM value so try this:

```
var quantity_j = document.getElementById("quantity_" + i).value;
var price_j = document.getElementById("price_" + i).value;
var amount_j = document.getElementById("amount_" + i).value;

amount_j = price_j * quantity_j;

document.getElementById("amount_" + i).value=amount_j;
```

Comment: also dear tell me what is difference between var quantity_j = document.getElementById("quantity_" + i) and then access this like quantity_j and  var quantity_j = document.getElementById("quantity_" + i).value and access it quantity_j.  :-) kindly focus on problem

Comment: @WaleedEhsan it shouldn't matter for the calculation, it just looks strange to grab the object when all you care about are the values. So I'm confused now. Are you trying to have the .value property of your input tag with id "amount" update based on the .value properties of the corresponding "price" and "quantity"? Or is the problem that your code isn't even running in the first place (i.e. if you put an alert("Hello"); in the function does it show up)?

Answer (score 0):

```
// @see http://jsfiddle.net/scafa/GFsPY/

$(document).ready(function(){
  // creating some sample data rows
  var tb = $("<tbody>");
  for(var i=1;i<=10;i++){
    var row = $("<tr>");
    row.append($("<td>").html(i));
    row.append($("<td>").html("A"+i));
     row.append($("<td>").html($("<input>").attr("size",8).val(Math.round(Math.random()*10))));    
     row.append($("<td>").html($("<input>").attr("size",8).val(Math.round(Math.random()*100))));    
     row.append($("<td>").append($("<input>")));
     tb.append(row);   
  }
  $("table").append(tb);

  // calculating
  $("table input").bind("blur", function(){
    var total = 0;
    $.each($("table tbody tr"), function(i, r){
      var fields = $(r).find("input");
      $(fields[2]).val($(fields[0]).val() * $(fields[1]).val());
      total += parseInt($(fields[2]).val());
    });
    $(".total").val(total);
  });

});
```

While having no PHP environment I just wrote a fiddle. Maybe this gives you a hint how to solve your problem. Don't blame me, I just hacked it in few minutes. But it works.
This is only an example!